# Quote Bash Problem

Tags: bash

Here is my code.

I can give why I do this code.
I try to take 1 file, take a line and guess if this line 1 have any "*", if yes, I change to the second file and try to see if the line 1 have "*" if no, I keep the data of file2/line1 and get in the final file.

But my question is: How doing an escape quote ?

```
#! /bin/bash
compteur="1"
ligne="2"
rm testfinal 2>/dev/null
touch testfinal 2>/dev/null
#########BOUCLE PERMUTATION LIGNE

while (( $ligne < "32" ))
do
        if [ 'cat test$compteur | sed -n $ligne\p | awk -F" "'{print $2}' ' == "*" ]
        then compteur=$((compteur+1));
        else
                   cat test$compteur | sed -n $ligne\p >> testfinal
                   ligne=$((ligne+1));
                   compteur=$((compteur=1));
fi
done
```

Edit: I find myself, the answers his:
if [ "`sed -n $ligne\p  test$compteur | awk -F" " '{print $2}'`" == "*" ]

Comment: The "solution" you mention in your edit will absolutely not work as you appear to intend.  The string `"sed [et cetera]"` will never be equal to `"*"`, the test will always fail, and the `else` clause will execute for literally every single case.

Answer (score 1):

Your example command doesn't make any sense.  You have no `then` or `fi` to go with your `if`, and you are incorrectly stuffing commands into a `test` (i. e. `[`) block.

Your code:

```
if [ 'cat test$compteur | sed -n $ligne\p | awk -F" " '{print $2}' ' == "*" ]
```

It *looks* like you're trying to compare the output of that chain of commands, and if the output is literally `*`, then do some undetermined thing?  If so:

```
if [[ "$( cat test$computer | sed -n $ligne\p | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')" == "*" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

But this can be optimized a little bit; not least by getting rid of your "useless use of `cat`:

```
if [[ "$( sed -n $ligne\p test$computer | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')" == "*" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

I'm not sure about what you're doing with your `sed` command, but presuming that `linge` is a variable containing a line number to print, this could even be done just in `awk`:

```
if [[ "$( awk -F' ' -v ln=$linge 'NR==ln { print $2 }' )" == "*" test$computer ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

Taking the full script you have submitted in your "answer", I have rewritten it with this changes and a couple of other small tweaks:

```
#!/bin/bash
compteur="1"
ligne="2"
> testfinal # clears contents of file in one step rather than rm; touch
#########BOUCLE PERMUTATION LIGNE

while [[ "$ligne" -lt 32 ]]; do
    if [[ "$( awk -F' ' -v ln=$ligne 'NR==ln { print $2 }' test$computer )" == "*" ]]; then
        compteur=$((compteur+1));
    else
        awk -v ln=$ligne 'NR==ln' >> testfinal
        ligne=$((ligne+1))
        compteur=$((compteur+1)); # I presume that the original 'compteur=1' was a typo.
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you mix up single quotes `'` and back ticks " `` " ? With back ticks (the old, deprecated "command substitution", equivalent to the new `$(...)`), your code line would make some sense, nonwithstanding GopeGhoti's improvement proposals.

Comment: No, I try but that's don't work :(